# Stretch the sidebar to full height of the page

Tags: html, css

I have this: http://jsfiddle.net/s75ew662/7/

How can I stretch the left sidebar (gray) to the full height of the page?

```css
.container {
    width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    background: lightgrey;
    float: left;
}
.content {
    background: lightblue;
    float: left;
    width: 550px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way based on your current code is to use [viewport units](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

```
.sidebar {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.container {
    width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    background: lightgrey;
    float: left;
    height: 100vh;
}
.content {
    background: lightblue;
    float: left;
    width: 550px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you need to support older browsers, you could do this instead.

```
html, body, .container{
    height: 100%;
}
.sidebar {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

```css
html, body, .container{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.container {
    width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    background: lightgrey;
    float: left;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.content {
    background: lightblue;
    float: left;
    width: 550px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In order to fix the the scrolling + overflow issues when the content is taller than the sidebar. Some slight markup changes would be needed, see the [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/u9um0ysu/) demo.

```css
html, body, .container {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.container {
    width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}
.sidebar {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 200px;
}
.content {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 550px;
}
.sidebar .inner {
    height: 100%;
    background: lightgrey;
}
.content .inner {
    background: lightblue;
}
.content .inner div {
    height: 100px; /*testing*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="inner">
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="inner">
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>3</div>
            <div>4</div>
            <div>5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The second solution doesn't work when the content gets much larger: http://jsfiddle.net/s75ew662/14/

Comment: I didn't notice that, but you can simply change sidebar to min-height:100%

Comment: Again, if the CONTENT gets larger, not the sidebar, your solution doesn't work (scroll down): http://jsfiddle.net/2ymubm3r/1/

Comment: `vh` units aren't all that well supported. I'd rather not use them.

Comment: viewport units are actually fairly well supported. Unless you're using Opera mini you'll be able to use them just fine. IE doesn't support `vmax` which isn't referenced here. http://caniuse.com/#search=vh

Comment: @NathanCox agreed. I also have the same link in the answer, very often it's get ignored.

Answer (score 0):

As a very simple solution, you can use the `vh` unit of measure, which corresponds to percentage of viewport height.

```
.sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: lightgrey;
    float: left;
}
```

Keep in mind that when doing this you need to account for the margins that are in place. I've posted a working example as a fork to your jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/01ubpbfg/

Answer (score 0):

In the css file, add the following to the sidebar class:

```
height:100vh;
```

Comment: `vh` isn't as supported as I need it to be.

Answer (score 0):

*Updated to solve overflow issue*

adding these four css styles would accomplish this:

```
html {
height: 100%;
}
body {
height: 100%;
}
.container {
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
.sidebar {
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work when the content gets much larger: http://jsfiddle.net/s75ew662/14/

Comment: try adding overflow: hidden; to the container class, that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/s75ew662/17/

```
.sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    background: lightgrey;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A very late reply, none of the above helped me. I have a working solution, may help someone. using a flex along with view port for min-height helps to cover the sidebar to the whole page.

this code assumes having a top-bar of height 51px;

```
.user-content {
  display: flex;
 }

.user-content .side-bar-content {
    flex      : 1;
    flex      : 0 0 220px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 51px);
    //min-height: 100vh; // without topbar
  }

 .user-content .app-user {
    flex   : 2;
    padding: 0 0 15px 15px;
  }
```